# Understanding Dell Nautilus Driver

Tags: hard-drive, drivers

On an old Dell PC (Precision T7400), a 4TB drive is only recognized as a 2TB drive. I found this driver on the Dell Support website:
http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=CVM50&fileId=3328295004&osCode=BIOSA&productCode=precision-t7400&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SA

What is the Nautilus firmware, and will it help me with the hard drive issue?

Comment: format the disk to GPT instead of MBR. However if T7400 don't support UEFI, you can't boot from it, has be used for storage only.

Comment: I converted the disk to GPT but it still shows only 2 TB.

Comment: That software you linked to is for Dell Servers and precision workstations, your model is not on the list., no it wont help you.

Comment: Most hard drive manufactures have utilities to format it correctly.

Comment: [See here](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/218619en)

Comment: Moab, actually my T7400 is one of the models listed for "Nautilus" driver. But what is this driver exactly? Will it change something on my Western Digital harddrive, or will it update drivers on my Dell PC?